# How can I write a function that can be used to initialize a static?

Tags: rust

This works:

```
static mutex: std::sync::Mutex<Object> =
    std::sync::Mutex::new(Object { field: BTreeMap::new() });
```

and this does not:

```
static mutex: std::sync::Mutex<Object> =
    std::sync::Mutex::new(Object::new());

struct Object {
    field: BTreeMap<String, String>,
}

impl Object {
    fn new() -> Object {
        Object { field: BTreeMap::new() }
    }
}
```

Why, and what is the resolution?

Comment: Please add a [mre]. Including **why** this doesn't work, ie the error message, desired vs actual behavior ....

Comment: Actually did you even read the error ["cannot call non-const fn `Object::new` in statics"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0015.html) along with the linked explanation seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: More to the point, this will compile if you change `fn new()` to `const fn new()`.

Answer (score 1):

A function can only be used as an initializer for a `static` variable if the function is marked `const`, meaning, it can be evaluated at compile time.

Only a limited amount of functionality is available inside of a `const` function. Luckily everything in your `new()` function **is** compatible with `const`, so adding the `const` keyword to your function will fix your compiler error.

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

static mutex: std::sync::Mutex<Object> = std::sync::Mutex::new(Object::new());

struct Object {
    field: BTreeMap<String, String>,
}

impl Object {
    const fn new() -> Object {
        Object {
            field: BTreeMap::new(),
        }
    }
}
```